# Nikon AF-S NIKKOR lens jammed

Tags: lens, nikon

After a recent road trip, I noticed that my Nikon AF-S NIKKOR 18-55mm lens was damaged while packing, and now seems jammed. If you observe the photo you will see that the lens is stuck at an angle, which seems to prevent it from moving at all. I can not rotate the lens, or move it up & down.

[image]

Is this a simple fix, or is the lens at least salvageable?

Comment: This is a perfect example of why lenses should always be stored with zoom and focus elements in their most retracted position.

Comment: Of course it SHOULD have but it wasn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal take on this is that it certainly needs to be sent in for repair. 
Whacking it on a table until it's straight probably wouldn't give you optimum results.

The repair depot should be able to give you a quote. You can then determine if the cost of repair exceeds your budget.

In any case, not a simple fix.

Comment: any ideas on what is going on inside there?

Comment: I have no actual knowledgeable idea, but I can guess. The zoom assembly has been torn off it's helical track. The angle of the lens tube tells me that it's -really- broken, as opposed to just a little bit. Here's a disassembly manual for the lens (or a nearby version). Take a look. http://allphotolenses.com/public/files/pdfs/62b36c4e422eb327a4b716cc961ab6c0.pdf